# Flutter add clickable link/url to a CheckboxListTile

Tags: flutter

I have a CheckboxListTile and a widget in the title tag. How can I create a html text (text + url) to this widget?

```
My text is: 'Hello <a href="www.aaa.aa">Click here</a>!'
```

I tried this: **flutter_html: ^0.10.4**

with no luck

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**
You can try [link: ^1.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/link#-installing-tab-)

```
import 'package:link/link.dart';
...
 Link(
    child: Text('This is a link to Flutter', style: TextStyle(
       decoration: TextDecoration.underline, // add add underline in text
    ),),
   url: 'https://google.com',
   onError: _showErrorSnackBar,
 ),

 void _showErrorSnackBar() {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('Oops... the URL couldn\'t be opened!'),
      ),
    );
  }
...
```

Output:

[image]

---

Have you tried [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#-installing-tab-),

```
RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchURL,
        child: Text('Text'),
      ),
```

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
```

---

You can also try [linkify](https://pub.dev/packages/linkify#-readme-tab-)

```
linkify("Made by https://cretezy.com");
```

Comment: @lacas See my updated answer and tell me if this is what you are looking for. if not then please try to add expected output in the question itself!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [flutter_linkify](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify).

You need to replace `Text` with `Linkify` widget.

With this plugin you code might look like this:

```dart
Linkify(
  onOpen: (link) => print("Clicked ${link.url}!"),
  text: "Made by https://cretezy.com",
);
```

Comment: not working, I want to show the link as a html like here in the comment

Comment: can you provide more details for what exactly you want that can not be done using the above solution?

If you are having any errors, add them here, so that we can get to the solution which works for your need.

Comment: how can we do it in Dart only, not in Flutter? Expected output: `Made by <a href="https://cretezy.com">https://cretezy.com</a>`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamlesh I am not sure what you mean by that. how are you going to display the text without a front-end? You must resort to flutter or HTML at the very least to show a clickable text.

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi Thank you so much for your reply. I have found the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68783041/10329023